# Call to undefined method craft\helpers\Stringy::langSpecificCharsArray() Craft 3

Tags: craftcms

Hi I have problem with Craft CMS after deploy I have an error if try to login /admin/login
I try to remove the vendor and install composer again but is the same.
How I can fix this issue sometimes if a manual move is working and after deploy, I make composer update, get this error.

```
    Call to undefined method craft\helpers\Stringy::langSpecificCharsArray()

1. in /var/www/developion_website/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Stringy.phpat line 32
23242526272829303132333435363738394041 
    /**
     * Public wrapper for [[langSpecificCharsArray()]].
     *
     * @param string $language Language of the source string
     * @return array An array of replacements
     */

    public static function getLangSpecificCharsArray(string $language = 'en'): array
    {
        return static::langSpecificCharsArray($language);
    }

    // Public Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * Public wrapper for [[charsArray()]].
     *
     * @return array
```

Here is my composer.json

```
    {
  "require": {
    "craftcms/ckeditor": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "craftcms/cms": "3.2.10",
    "ether/seo": "3.6.2",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
    "xpertbot/craft-wheelform": "2.2.4"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not get Composer to update correctly either and had to bypass it with Craft's CLI tool to obtain the minor version patch that corrects this issue.

In a terminal, running the following bumped my lockfile and fixed the issue:

```
php craft update all
```

Comment: Which version (of Stringy?) was it that corrected the issue? I have had no luck trying the same as you.